# Issue related with material-ui Autocomplete control with checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have Autocomplete control with checkboxes. In this link there is demo, https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-wozniak-hu2l45?file=/src/inner.js
Currently checkboxes are not checkable, but when we change line 84 as

```
   - options={options2}
   + options={options}
```

it works, or when we comment line 88

```
//setSelectedValues(val);
```

it also works. What can be the problem? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove your `const` variable(`options2`) outside your functional component just after all imports at line 9. It will work.